# Embedding Facebook posts via iframe not working

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe

I'm attempting to embed a facebook post onto a website. I took Facebook's most basic example and plugged it into the html. On the page I see a big empty space, but no embed post. If I visit Chrome or Safari this looks perfectly fine. I'm using Firefox 47. What's interesting is that in Firefox when I visit the iframe tag I see the following generated html.

Generated html for embedded post:

```
<iframe style="border: none; overflow: hidden;" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F20531316728%2Fposts%2F10154009990506729%2F&amp;width=500&amp;show_text=true&amp;height=290&amp;appId" width="500" height="290" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Code inside `iframe`:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure it’s not some add-on or privacy mode blocking the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded Firefox 47.0 for Mac and tested your code. It opens here!

Attached is a screenshot. Sorry, this is no answer, but I cannot attach an image in a comment. So chose to answer.[Screenshot on Firefox 47.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5TaW.png)